# Add a new header row starting from 0 to a csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file and has its own column header already.
I would like to add a new header row starting from 0. (0,1,2,3,4,5...)

anyone has idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `header=None` for default columns names with skip actual csv header by `skiprows=1` parameter if DataFrame is created by [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, skiprows=1)
```

If Dataframe is created different way - e.g. from list, dict.. is possible assign `range` to columns names:

```
df.columns = range(len(df.columns))
```

Comment: it does not work tho. previously I have 'df = pd.DataFrame(pairs_.values(), columns=titles )', not sure if anything got into the way

Comment: @yasukunishrine - Use `df.columns = range(len(df.columns))`, added to answer,.

Comment: @yasukunishrine - Or try `df = pd.DataFrame(pairs_.values())`

Comment: @yasukunishrine - `I have a csv file` is in question, so DataFrame is not created by `read_csv` ?